# C# MetaData API create Object and Field

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, c#

I am getting an error message on the last line of: unexpected Login : Object not set to the instance of an object. Any ideas?

```
            MetadataService.CustomObject co = new MetadataService.CustomObject();
            co.deploymentStatus = MetadataService.DeploymentStatus.Deployed;
            co.deploymentStatusSpecified = true;
            co.description = "My Custom Object created from .NET";
            co.fullName = "DotNetCustomObject__c";
            co.label = "DotNet Custom Object";
            co.pluralLabel = "DotNet Custom Objects";
            co.sharingModel = MetadataService.SharingModel.ReadWrite;
            co.sharingModelSpecified = true;
            co.nameField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
            co.nameField.type = MetadataService.FieldType.Text;
            co.nameField.label = "The Name";
            co.nameField.length = 100;
            co.nameField.lengthSpecified = true;

            MetadataService.SaveResult[] results = ms.createMetadata(new Metadata[] { co });
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a little bit of time to figure out how to get this however below is part of what I did to correct. I will say that salesforce and other posts state that you have to remove all [][] from the reference files however you are not. You are only supposed to remove them from the errors that come when trying to hit the MetadataService.

```
                MetadataService.CustomObject co = new MetadataService.CustomObject();
                co.deploymentStatus = MetadataService.DeploymentStatus.Deployed;
                co.deploymentStatusSpecified = true;
                co.description = "My Custom Object created from .NET";
                co.fullName = "ACustomObjectInDotNet2__c";
                co.label = "ACustomObjectInDotNet2";
                co.pluralLabel = "ACustomObjectInDotNets2";
                co.sharingModel = MetadataService.SharingModel.ReadWrite;
                co.sharingModelSpecified = true;
                co.nameField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
                co.nameField.type = MetadataService.FieldType.Text;
                co.nameField.label = "The Name";
                co.nameField.length = 100;
                co.nameField.lengthSpecified = true;
                co.enableActivities = true;
                co.nameField.typeSpecified = true;
                MetadataService.UpsertResult[] results = ms.upsertMetadata(new Metadata[] { co });
```